Get a work schedule template based on date range
I have a table in my MariaDB 10.3 database with schedule templates for my workers, which are then used in a schedule planner. When there is a modification to the employee's employment contract, a new set of records is added with the new schedule.
So far I have the following query:
SELECT
    ehp.id_pers_empleado employee_id,
    ehp.diasem weekday,
    ehp.hora_inicio `from`,
    ehp.hora_fin `to`,
    ehp.validez `starts`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, ehp.hora_inicio, ehp.hora_fin ) / 60 worked
FROM
    empleados_horarios_predeterminados ehp 
WHERE
    id_pers_empleado = 476 
ORDER BY
    `starts`,
    weekday 

That query returns the following fields:



field
type
description




employee_id
int
Employee ID


weekday
int
1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)


from
time
Start time of the work shift


to
time
End time of the work shift


starts
date
Date from which this record becomes valid


hours
float
Hours the employee will work (to save time)



In this way, the records I obtain are the following:



employee_id
weekday
from
to
starts
worked




00000476
1
09:00:00
14:00:00
2024-04-01
5.0000


00000476
2
09:00:00
14:00:00
2024-04-01
5.0000


00000476
3
09:00:00
14:00:00
2024-04-01
5.0000


00000476
4
09:00:00
14:00:00
2024-04-01
5.0000


00000476
5
09:00:00
14:00:00
2024-04-01
5.0000


00000476
1
07:00:00
15:30:00
2024-05-01
8.5000


00000476
2
07:00:00
15:00:00
2024-05-01
8.0000


00000476
3
07:00:00
15:00:00
2024-05-01
8.0000


00000476
4
07:00:00
15:00:00
2024-05-01
8.0000


00000476
5
07:00:00
15:00:00
2024-05-01
8.0000


5
1
09:00:00
14:00:00
2020-04-30
5.0000


5
1
18:00:00
21:00:00
2020-04-30
3.0000


5
2
09:00:00
14:00:00
2020-04-30
5.0000


5
2
18:00:00
21:00:00
2020-04-30
3.0000


5
3
09:00:00
14:00:00
2020-04-30
5.0000


5
3
18:00:00
21:00:00
2020-04-30
3.0000


5
4
09:00:00
14:00:00
2020-04-30
5.0000


5
4
18:00:00
21:00:00
2020-04-30
3.0000


5
5
09:00:00
14:00:00
2020-04-30
5.0000


5
5
18:00:00
21:00:00
2020-04-30
3.0000


5
1
09:00:00
14:00:00
2020-05-01
5.0000


5
1
18:00:00
21:00:00
2020-05-01
3.0000


5
2
09:00:00
14:00:00
2020-05-01
5.0000


5
2
18:00:00
21:00:00
2020-05-01
3.0000


5
3
09:00:00
14:00:00
2020-05-01
5.0000


5
3
18:00:00
21:00:00
2020-05-01
3.0000


5
4
09:00:00
14:00:00
2020-05-01
5.0000


5
4
18:00:00
21:00:00
2020-05-01
3.0000


5
6
10:00:00
14:00:00
2020-05-01
4.0000


5
6
20:00:00
00:00:00
2020-05-01
4.0000


5
1
08:00:00
14:00:00
2020-05-27
6.0000


5
1
17:00:00
20:00:00
2020-05-27
3.0000


5
2
08:00:00
14:00:00
2020-05-27
6.0000


5
3
08:00:00
14:00:00
2020-05-27
6.0000


5
3
17:00:00
20:00:00
2020-05-27
3.0000


5
4
08:00:00
14:00:00
2020-05-27
6.0000


5
4
17:00:00
20:00:00
2020-05-27
3.0000


5
5
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-05-27
7.0000


5
1
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-07-03
7.0000


5
2
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-07-03
7.0000


5
3
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-07-03
7.0000


5
4
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-07-03
7.0000


5
5
08:00:00
14:00:00
2020-07-03
6.0000


5
1
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-08-25
7.0000


5
1
16:00:00
20:00:00
2020-08-25
4.0000


5
2
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-08-25
7.0000


5
3
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-08-25
7.0000


5
3
16:00:00
20:00:00
2020-08-25
4.0000


5
4
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-08-25
7.0000


5
4
16:00:00
20:00:00
2020-08-25
4.0000


5
5
08:00:00
14:00:00
2020-08-25
6.0000


5
1
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-10-28
7.0000


5
2
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-10-28
7.0000


5
2
16:00:00
18:30:00
2020-10-28
2.5000


5
3
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-10-28
7.0000


5
4
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-10-28
7.0000


5
4
16:00:00
18:30:00
2020-10-28
2.5000


5
5
08:00:00
15:00:00
2020-10-28
7.0000


5
1
07:30:00
15:00:00
2022-09-19
7.5000


5
2
07:30:00
15:00:00
2022-09-19
7.5000


5
3
07:30:00
15:00:00
2022-09-19
7.5000


5
4
07:30:00
15:00:00
2022-09-19
7.5000


5
4
16:00:00
18:30:00
2022-09-19
2.5000


5
5
07:30:00
15:00:00
2022-09-19
7.5000


5
1
07:00:00
15:00:00
2023-06-19
8.0000


5
2
07:00:00
15:00:00
2023-06-19
8.0000


5
3
07:00:00
15:00:00
2023-06-19
8.0000


5
4
07:00:00
15:00:00
2023-06-19
8.0000


5
5
07:00:00
15:00:00
2023-06-19
8.0000


5
1
07:30:00
15:00:00
2023-09-26
7.5000


5
2
07:30:00
15:00:00
2023-09-26
7.5000


5
3
07:30:00
15:00:00
2023-09-26
7.5000


5
4
07:30:00
15:00:00
2023-09-26
7.5000


5
4
16:00:00
18:30:00
2023-09-26
2.5000


5
5
07:30:00
15:00:00
2023-09-26
7.5000



I need to know what work schedule the employee had in a specific date range.
For example, if I query the week from 4/29/2024 to 5/5/2024, I would expect to receive:

Monday 04/29 → Day of week 1 of the schedule that began on 04/01/2024
Tuesday 04/30 → Day of week 2 of the schedule that began on 04/01/2024
Wednesday 05/01 → Day of week 3 of the schedule that began on 05/01/2024
Thursday 05/02 → Day of week 4 of the schedule that began on 05/01/2024
Friday 05/03 → Day of week 5 of the schedule that began on 05/01/2024

That is, the following set of records for employee 476:



employee_id
date
from
to
starts
worked




00000476
2024-04-29
09:00:00
14:00:00
2024-04-01
5.0000


00000476
2024-04-30
09:00:00
14:00:00
2024-04-01
5.0000


00000476
2024-05-01
07:00:00
15:00:00
2024-05-01
8.0000


00000476
2024-05-02
07:00:00
15:00:00
2024-05-01
8.0000


00000476
2024-05-03
07:00:00
15:00:00
2024-05-01
8.0000



With this data I want to know how many hours that employee had worked that week, or automatically create the schedule for future weeks.
I've been racking my brain all day trying to find a way to make it possible, but everything I try doesn't give the expected result.
Last try was:
WITH RECURSIVE date_range (`date`) AS (
    SELECT '2023-09-25' -- start date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM date_range WHERE `date` < '2023-10-01' -- end date
),
ehp AS (
    SELECT *, LEAD(validez) OVER (PARTITION BY diasem ORDER BY validez) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS validez_fin
    FROM empleados_horarios_predeterminados
    WHERE id_pers_empleado = 5
)
SELECT 
  ehp.id_pers_empleado employee_id,
  dr.`date`,
  ehp.hora_inicio `from`,
  ehp.hora_fin `to`,
  ehp.validez `starts`,
  ehp.validez_fin `ends`,
  (TIME_TO_SEC(ehp.hora_fin) - TIME_TO_SEC(ehp.hora_inicio)) / 3600 AS worked
FROM date_range dr
JOIN ehp ON WEEKDAY(dr.`date`) + 1 = ehp.diasem
  AND ehp.validez <= dr.`date`
  AND (ehp.validez_fin >= dr.`date` OR ehp.validez_fin IS NULL);

Which gave me the correct resultset for the specific case I've been talking, but I'm encountering problems with other users with older schedule templates or multiple shifts in same day.
When I'm querying for employee 5 (an old one) in date range between "2023-09-25" and "2023-10-01", it's resulting in the following recordset:



employee_id
date
weekday
from
to
starts
ends
worked




5
2023-09-25
1
07:00:00
15:00:00
2023-06-19
2023-09-25
8.0000


5
2023-09-26
2
07:30:00
15:00:00
2023-09-26
null
7.5000


5
2023-09-27
3
07:30:00
15:00:00
2023-09-26
null
7.5000


5
2023-09-28
4
16:00:00
18:30:00
2023-09-26
null
2.5000


5
2023-09-29
5
07:30:00
15:00:00
2023-09-26
null
7.5000


5
2023-09-30
6
20:00:00
00:00:00
2020-05-01
null
-20.0000



First problem: it's not showing the shift from 07:30 to 15:00 for weekday 4.
Second problem: it's showing a record for weekday 6 from a very old schedule template, long time ago deprecated by newer ones.
Third problem: it's not calculating correctly shifts ending after 23:59, resulting in negative working hours.

To correctly handle the three problems stated in your update, you can add a CTE (schedules below) to identify the validez dates of the shift templates applicable for the employee and date range required:
SET @start_date = '2023-09-25', @end_date = '2023-10-01', @employee = 5;

WITH RECURSIVE date_range (dt) AS (
    SELECT @start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM date_range WHERE dt < @end_date
),
schedules (validez, validez_fin) AS (
    SELECT validez, COALESCE(LEAD(validez) OVER (ORDER BY validez) - INTERVAL 1 DAY, @end_date)
    FROM empleados_horarios_predeterminados
    WHERE validez BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(validez) FROM empleados_horarios_predeterminados WHERE id_pers_empleado = @employee AND validez <= @start_date)
                      AND (SELECT MAX(validez) FROM empleados_horarios_predeterminados WHERE id_pers_empleado = @employee AND validez <= @end_date)
    AND id_pers_empleado = @employee
    GROUP BY validez
)
SELECT
    dr.dt,
    ehp.*,
    (TIME_TO_SEC(IF(ehp.hora_fin < ehp.hora_inicio, ehp.hora_fin + INTERVAL 24 HOUR, ehp.hora_fin)) - TIME_TO_SEC(ehp.hora_inicio)) / 3600 AS worked
FROM date_range dr
JOIN schedules s
    ON dr.dt BETWEEN s.validez AND s.validez_fin
JOIN empleados_horarios_predeterminados ehp
    ON ehp.id_pers_empleado = @employee
    AND s.validez = ehp.validez
    AND WEEKDAY(dr.dt) + 1 = ehp.diasem
ORDER BY dr.dt, ehp.hora_inicio;

Here's another db<>fiddle.
Or you could add a correlated subquery to the result of the date_range CTE:
SET @start_date = '2023-09-25', @end_date = '2023-10-01', @employee = 5;

WITH RECURSIVE date_range (dt) AS (
    SELECT @start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM date_range WHERE dt < @end_date
),
dr_with_validez AS (
    SELECT *,
        (
            SELECT MAX(validez)
            FROM empleados_horarios_predeterminados
            WHERE id_pers_empleado = @employee
            AND validez <= dr.dt
        ) AS validez
    FROM date_range dr
)
SELECT
    dr.dt,
    ehp.*,
    (TIME_TO_SEC(IF(ehp.hora_fin < ehp.hora_inicio, ehp.hora_fin + INTERVAL 24 HOUR, ehp.hora_fin)) - TIME_TO_SEC(ehp.hora_inicio)) / 3600 AS worked
FROM dr_with_validez dr
JOIN empleados_horarios_predeterminados ehp
    ON ehp.id_pers_empleado = @employee
    AND dr.validez = ehp.validez
    AND WEEKDAY(dr.dt) + 1 = ehp.diasem
ORDER BY dr.dt, ehp.hora_inicio;

db<>fiddle
We don't know all your use cases but you might want to consider splitting the current table to separate the shift template and the days/times of the individual shifts:
shift_templates (id, id_pers_empleado, validez)
shift_template_shifts (shift_template_id, diasem, hora_inicio, hora_fin)


This looks great but I forgot to mention I'm working with MariaDB 10.3 so the JOIN LATERAL part won't work for me. That was my bad so I'll edit my question to match the correct DB engine.

Ok I tried that exhaustively and I found 3 problems. I've edited your fiddle to add some real data from other employee. The problems are:
First, if employee had more multiple shifts in the same day (e.g. one from 7:00 to 15:00 and one from 16:00 to 18:30) it'll only show the second one. It'd be correct to show both of them for my purpose.
Second, if employee had a very old shift template for a day it's not present in the most recent records, it'll show anyway even when it's clear (for humans) they're not valid anymore.

Third, shifts ending after 23:59 are no calculating correcty, resulting in negative worked hours. Althought that is simple for me to fix adding an IF clause to the worked field.
Here is the edited fiddle.

With "clear (for humans)" I mean that is clear for a human that a recordset with a validity date automatically invalidates all previous ones. So if I'm querying a date range between "2023-09-25" and "2023-10-01", there's no sense on show a record of "2020-05-01" in the result set since there are recordsets with later validity dates.
If there was a non-calculated validity_end field (which I'm thinking is gonna be the appropiate solution), it should show the day before the next recordset's validity.
I'll edit now my question to add the other employee's recordset.

Now it seems to work perfectly! Thank you very much for your help! I'm not so much advanced in MySQL to handle properly by myself and you saved my day!

Practice makes perfect. Happy learning!
